# When click on place order button payment failed in Magento2 with "Zend_Uri_Http" Error

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am using pleask server when I click on place order button then below error showing in magento2

I am using mage2pro stripe payment method and paypal.(order going failed)

```
[2019-02-20 18:00:41] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5c6d95c928204; Message: "Zend_Uri_Http" not found {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5c6d95c928204; Message: \"Zend_Uri_Http\" not found at /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, Zend_Uri_Exception(code: 0): \"Zend_Uri_Http\" not found at /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Uri.php:140)"} []
```

**AND**

```
Validate class not found from basename 'NotEmpty'
************************************
File:        vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Address/AbstractAddress.php
Line:        575
Caller:      Magento\Customer\Model\Address\AbstractAddress::validate
Callee:      Zend_Validate::is
Context:     
public function validate()
```